# Sitemap for resources on a shared server

Tags: sitemap

I have 3 sites that are all related. Recently, I bought a 4th domain just to serve as a resource manager and not actually deliver content. Similar to what Facebook does having all their scripts and stylesheets located at https://static.fbcdn.net/

The problem I am having is what to do for the sitemaps... If documents (like PDFs) are located on that server, how do I get those files indexed according to the site the uses them since the domain is different?

Answer (score 0):

You should use different sitemaps - every website should contain its own sitemap.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The new domain has no site, no content. It just servers resources. A sitemap on that site would be pointless and accomplish nothing. I am asking how to associate content on the resource domain with the other domains.